# A complete family tree

Tags: vocabulary, resource-request, familia

There are many Latin words for relatives: father, mother, brother, sister, son, daughter, uncle, aunt, cousin…
Different languages have slightly different sets of words for relatives and some words don't point at a unique kind of relative.
For example, the English "uncle" can mean a father's brother or a mother's brother and the Finnish "käly" means a spouse's sister or a brother's wife.
I don't exactly know what family words exist in Latin, apart from the most common ones.

**I would like to have a complete list of Latin words for relatives.**
It can be in the form of a family tree or simply as a list with written explanations.
Where can I find such a list?

Going through a dictionary and trying to compile such a list would be tedious, since I don't know what to look for.
Therefore it would make a huge difference to have a list.
Even a list without translations would do; I can check the meanings in a dictionary once I know what to look for.

The list I found on [this page](http://www.dl.ket.org/latin1/things/optional/famtree_project.htm) looks good, but I don't know if anything is missing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each new paragraph shows a new generation (g  means 'great'). Enclosures within (brackets) indicate the maternal side :

tritavus = tritavia *g.g.g.g.grandfather, mother*

atavus=atavia   *g.g.g.grandfather, mother*

patruus maximus *g.grand uncle* — amita maxima *aunt* — abavus *grandfather(=abavia — avunculus maximus *g.grand uncle* — matertera maxima *aunt*)

patruus maior *g.g.grand uncle* — amita maior *aunt* — proavus *grandfather(=proavia — avunculus maior *g.g.grand uncle* — matertera maior *aunt*)

patruus magnus *g.grand uncle* — amita magna *aunt* — avus *grandfather(=avia — avunculus magnus *g.grand uncle* — matertera magna *aunt*)

patruus *uncle* — amita *aunt* — pater *father*=(mater *mother — avunculus *uncle* — matertera *aunt*)

frater *or* levir *brother/wife’s brother-in-law* — soror *sister* — MARITUS=(UXOR — uxoris frater *husband’s brother-in-law — uxoris soror *or* glos*husband’s sister-in-law*

filius *son* = nurus *daughter-in-law — filia *daughter* =gener *son-in-law*

Note 1. Contemporary with pater=mater are socer *father-in-law* and socerus *mother-in-law*. The parents of these two are prosocer and prosocerus

Note 2. Cousins, whether the children of patruus/amita or avunculus/matertera are *consobrinus* and *consobrina*

Note 3. The grandchildren of MARITUS=UXOR are *nepos* and *neptis*, whose respective spouses are *pronurus* and *progener*. Their great-grandchildren are *pronepos* and *proneptis*.

Note 4. There are no special terms for nephews and nieces who are described as filius/filia of fratris/sororis.

Finally, there is an extra set to cover step-relations. If you think they are useful to you, or you would like them simply for the sake of completeness, they are *novercus*, stepmother and *vitricus*, stepfather. The step-children are *privignus* and *privigna*.

Answer (score 10):

Erasmus has a complete list of *vocabula affinitatum* ("words for in-laws") in his [*Colloquia*](https://books.google.com/books?id=yzoLQBZMzb8C&pg=PA40). This is post-classical, but Erasmus's Latin rivals that of Cicero. This definitely has some overlap with the previous answer:

> **Maritus**: husband
>   **Uxor**: wife
>   **Socer**: father-in-law (wife's father)
>   **Socrus**: mother-in-law (wife's mother)
>   **Gener**: son-in-law (daughter's husband)
>   **Nurus**: daughter-in-law (son's wife)
>   **Levir**: brother-in-law (husband's brother) - "Levir dicitur ab uxore ut Helena Hecto rem levirum vocat quod esset nupta Paridi"
>   **Glos**: sister-in-law (husband's sister)
>   **Fratria**: sister-in-law (brother's wife)
>   **Vitricus**: step-father (mother's husband)
>   **Noverca**: step-mother (father's wife)
>   **Privignus**:  step-son (wife or husband's son)
>   **Privigna**: step-daughter (wife or husband's daughter)

Conspicuously absent are words for "wife's brother," "wife's sister," "sister's husband," and possibly more. I made no effort to verify these words, but I'll try to look into this further when I have time.

And going a bit further, he also gives some less legitimate *affinitates*:

> **Rivalis**: wife's lover
>   **Pellex**: husband's lover ("ut Thraso rivalis est Phaedriae et Europe pellex est Junoni")

Comment: Interestingly, Cicero Fin V. 23. 65, _Quae nata a primo satu, quod a procreatoribus nati  diliguntur et tota domus coniugio et stirpe coniungitur, serpit sensim foras,  cognationibus primum, tum affinitatibus, deinde amicitiis, post vicinitatibus, tum civibus . . . ._ distinguishes _affinitas_ from _cognatio_.

Answer (score 6):

I drew a family tree based on Tom Cotton's answer:

[image: Familia mea]

Some of the tree is hidden and the quality of the picture is not great.
To explore more, [see the dynamical family tree online](http://www.familyecho.com/?p=START&c=t75yvl3o&f=153099915162860489).

If anyone knows a tool for making the whole tree visible at the same time (or wants to draw the tree), I would be happy to know.

Comment: Amazing! Why did you open the tree branch to the right? Maybe to the center would have been more neat?

Comment: @luchonacho Thanks! This was a fun little project for the first day of my vacation. I chose to focus on paternal ancestors (as I imagine a Roman would). That's the way the software positions the people. It would not not allow me to change some of the left-right orientations that I find clumsy, nor expand everything at once. I agree, a central positioning would look better. I just picked the first reasonable-looking free online tool, and I'm open to ideas. I think this tree deserves to be neatly formatted somewhere in the internet.

Answer (score 4):

And here's a visual representation of a Roman family.

You can see the words PATER, VXOR, and F (filius).

[image]

cf. another very famous inscription - the Epitaph of Agrippina the Elder (i.e. Caligula's mother), CIL 6.886:

[image]

Comment: Do you know if it was more common to see *uxor* rather than *mater* in this context? It would be interesting if all relations were defined relative to the *paterfamilias*.

Comment: @brianpck That would make a great question! That kind of naming convention would make sense, but I've never heard of anything about the topic.

Comment: @brianpck It certainly wouldn't be *mater*, since it's not the tomb of the underage son. That said, daughters, mothers, and wives are frequently mentioned, but unless they share their husband's tomb, they have their own epitaph. [See here e.g](http://www.vroma.org/images/raia_images/cippus_papinia.jpg). This is largely my impression from seeing hundreds of epitaphs in Rome, so it might be different outside the *urbs*.

Comment: @brianpck I just added another example.